# Put a resource string (from infoPlist.strings) on info.plist

Tags: ios, localization, info.plist

I have my `infoPlist.strings` with my localizable strings. I want to add on my `info.plist` the resource I added. How do I accomplish that?

On `Infoplist.strings`:

`"NSAppleMusicUsageDescription" = "My description";`

On `Info.plist`:

`NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription - $(NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription)`

`NSAppleMusicUsageDescription - $(NSAppleMusicUsageDescription)`

Or changing `$` for `@` is not working either...

Thank you

Comment: On Info.plist:
put permission with any language it doesn't matter every time app take the localizable message from every  localized Infoplist.strings file

Comment: So the way it is, is the solution? Instead of $(...) put the whole message?

Comment: unfortunately,  i can't understand what you want to say. so I make an answer example and not know what you mean by using   $ ,  @ and $(permission2)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> STEP-I : On `Info.plist` put the default value

[image: Info.plist]

> STEP-II : Create `Infoplist.strings` file and localize it to all supported  languages

[image]

> STEP-III : On each `Infoplist.strings` file put localized values to every key you want to localize its messages

[image]

The application uses the Info.plist key-value as a default value if it didn't find a specific language file. so, you can put English value in the Info.plist file and translate other languages in specific localizable file

Comment: ok, let me try. is it which the `"`? or without? I am talking about the name of the string on `Step III`...

Comment: if it does not work make sure you use the same key because it works well with me

Comment: Worked. Thanks. Why it works without the `"`? Like normal strings? (Marked as answer already)

Comment: Why it works without the "? or Why it doesn't work without the "? 
you say it worked with my answer and I put the " in it, sorry but I don't  understand what you say

Comment: @MagdyZamel minor note: "Loaclizable" in InfoPlist.strings example